# Bind and Unbind a Started service

Tags: android-activity, android-service, media-player

I am making a media player foreground app. I want to ask that should i start, and bound service each time i press the play button or start and bind on onStart() method.Similarly unbind and stopService on pause button or implement it in inStop() method?

Answer (score 0):

Bind and Unbind in `onStart` and `onStop` so your service will be running and be able to play any track you want faster.